# Replace every occurence of X in a string by not knowing the whole X

Tags: php, regex

I need to do something like the following:

```
$hashes = "hash_0000199a5e6d7781cc1bd6cf24f64dd6ffb423|hash_00001977087c71ad7073c31041e3ea503f79ce|hash_000019bc1896ab17d3a1b616c4e9a0fa6f06e0";
$hashes = preg_replace("hash_\d{6}", "", $hashes);
```

`$hashes` should now contain the same as before only without all `hash_000019`. The first 6 numbers can change, that's why I need the regex to contain something like `\d{6}`

I'm probably doing the regex thing wrong. I hope you understand what my problem is.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first parameter needs a "delimiter" in the search.

```
preg_replace('/hash_\d{6}/', '', $hashes);
```

Comment: ahh, I always forget that with PHP. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to add delimiters to the regular expression:

```
$hashes = preg_replace("/hash_\d{6}/", "", $hashes);
```

There are loads of possibilities other than `/`, but the chosen delimiter has to be escaped. Read up on delimiters [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php).

Comment: then please accept one of our answers... his was a few seconds faster, mine has the link... it's for you to decide ;)

Comment: accepted his, because you have aloot of reputation already :)) thanks again btw